Name for Generalized Generalized Linear Models
Consider the class of models given by $y\sim F(g^{-1}(\beta^\top\mathbf{x}))$ with $\mathbb{E}[Y]=g^{-1}(\beta^\top\mathbf{x})$.
Most authors I've come across call this a GLM only if F is in the exponential family.
Is there a term for the more general case where $F$ might not be in the exponential family?

Unless there is a canonical answer to this (+1 btw) (which I expect there will be), then I think you have already answered the question: “Generalized Generalized Linear Models”

I don't think you'll get that past most reviewers or editors. I'd suggest "doubly generalized linear models".

What would be the use of such models? Is there a particular method of fitting them? To come up with a name, it would be helpful to not only consider this class of models, but also really visualize what they would mean.

@SextusEmpiricus I'm testing out a quite general (gradient-based) model fitting algo, and my first experiments are on this class of models for a bunch of likelihoods. I'm looking for a nice title for that subsection. Seems there may not be one!
